# Use compass for compiling Sass files

Tags: ionic-framework

Anyone knows how to include Compass in compiling Sass in Ionic?

Everytime I do `ionic serve` it gives me an error: `[gulp-sass] file to import not found or unreadable: compass`

Here's my Gulp task:

```
gulp.task('sass', function(done) {
  gulp.src('./scss/ionic.app.scss')
    .pipe(sass({
      compass: true,
      errLogToConsole: true
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./www/css/'))
    .pipe(minifyCss({
      keepSpecialComments: 0
    }))
    .pipe(rename({ extname: '.min.css' }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./www/css/'))
    .on('end', done);
});
```

I've also done `npm install -g gulp-compass` it still doesn't work.

Thanks

Comment: I think you should show the full gulpfile

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `Compass` instead of `Sass`, make sure you have `compass` installed `gem install sass`

Then install `gulp-compass` and replace `sass` in your gulp pipe.

Here's my new config:

```
var compass = require('gulp-compass');

gulp.task('sass', function(done) {
  gulp.src('./scss/ionic.app.scss')
    .pipe(compass({
      sass: 'scss',
      css: 'www/css'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./www/css/'))
    .pipe(minifyCss({
      keepSpecialComments: 0
    }))
    .pipe(rename({ extname: '.min.css' }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./www/css/'))
    .on('end', done);
});
```

Then as always, import `compass` in to your Sass stylesheets `@import "compass";`